# ¿Cómo crear carpeta en android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mkdir

Tengo un código que siempre me ha funcionado, el cual crea un directorio en la **"memoria interna"**:

```
String direc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/nombrecarpeta/";
```

y creo la carpeta con:

```
new File(direc).mkdirs();
```

recuerden que el

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
```

devuelve

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

funciona, pero en android 10 y posteriores ya no crea el directorio.

Entiendo que si se agrega en el manifest

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

en android 10 funcionara pero en android 11 ya no..

**la idea es no utilizar el**

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al tratar de crear tu directorio `/storage/emulated/0/nombrecarpeta/` mediante

```
String direc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/nombrecarpeta/";
```

comentas "funciona .. pero en android 10 y posteriores ya no."

Esto fue definido en la documentación, a partir de la API 29 ya no se tendrá acceso a ubicaciones fuera del directorio de tu aplicación, ahora tendrás que crear directorios y archivos dentro de la estructura definida por Android:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/
```

seguramente por cuestiones de seguridad.

Como comentas puedes definir temporalmente `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`  dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` para android 10 and 11, pero para futuras versiones del sistema operativo esto definitivamente se restringirá, por lo que te recomiendo usar ahora [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) para este propósito.

Ahora lo tienes que realizar de esta forma:

**Crear directorio usando [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))**

```
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/nombrecarpeta/");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
```

Esto creará el directorio y la estructura:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/nombrecarpeta/
```

---

**Crear archivo usando [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))**

```
  try {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "gerardfile.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Esto creará el archivo "gerardfile.txt" dentro de la estructura:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/gerardfile.txt
```

Comment: muchas gracias. ! eso quiere decir que desde android 10 y 11 no se poda grabar nada afuera de la carpeta raíz de la misma app