# Consulta para guardar archivos

Tags: java, android, archivo, sqlite

**Buenas, estoy teniendo problemas para guardar un archivo **CSV** creado a partir de una `Tabla` hecha en `SQLite`. Cuando veo el `Device File Explorer` al momento de guardar el archivo (usando el emulador - Nexus 4/API 24/Android 7) funciona de manera correcta, ya que al buscarlo lo encuentro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo se crea exitosamente y se puede visualizar de manera correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, cuando instalé la aplicación en mi dispositivo busqué la carpeta **TMO_Descarga** y no la encontré. Busqué el archivo **Lista.csv** y tampoco lo encontré:

***Nombre del paquete: com.dafran.booksearch**

[No existe la carpeta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzhzE.jpg)

[Tampoco se ve el nombre del paquete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVI7j.jpg)

[Buscándolo por nombre tampoco aparece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOkEx.jpg)

[Nombre + extensión tampoco aparece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD5Tc.jpg)

También intenté buscando solo la extensión **(csv/.csv)** pero tampoco aparece.

Este es mi método para exportar la tabla:

```
public void descargarLista() {
    File directorio = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TMO_Descarga");
    if(!directorio.exists()){
        directorio.mkdirs();
    }
    File archivo = new File(directorio, "Lista.csv");
    try{
        archivo.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
        this.openReadableDB();
        Cursor cursorCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TMOnlineTablasSQL.NOMBRE_MANGA + ", "+ TMOnlineTablasSQL.TIPO_MANGA + " FROM " + TMOnlineTablasSQL.TABLA_SEGUIR + " ORDER BY " + TMOnlineTablasSQL.NOMBRE_MANGA + " ASC", null);
        csvWriter.writeNext(cursorCSV.getColumnNames());
        while (cursorCSV.moveToNext()){
            String[] columnas = {cursorCSV.getString(0), cursorCSV.getString(1)};
            csvWriter.writeNext(columnas);
        }
        csvWriter.close();
        cursorCSV.close();
    }catch (Exception sqlException){
        Log.e("TMODescargaError", sqlException.getMessage(), sqlException);
    }
}
```

Y el botón donde lo utilizo:

```
    btnDescargarLista.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(pedirPermisoAlmacenamiento()){
                TMOnlineMetodosSQL tmOnlineMetodosSQL = new TMOnlineMetodosSQL(TMOnlineListaMangasSiguiendo.this);
                tmOnlineMetodosSQL.descargarLista();
            }else {
                toastRojo("Debe aceptar los permisos de almacenamiento.");
            }
        }
    });
```

El método de los permisos:

```
public  boolean pedirPermisoAlmacenamiento() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué no estoy viendo la carpeta ni el archivo en mi dispositivo?

**Actualización:**

He creado un `ADV PIXEL` con **Android R SDK 30**.

Con la respuesta escrita, opté por controlar el SDK del móvil para crear la carpeta, lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```
public void descargarLista(Context actividad) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29){
        //para targetSDK >= 29
        File directorio = new File(actividad.getExternalFilesDir(null), "TMO_Descarga");
        if(!directorio.exists()){
            directorio.mkdirs();
        }
        File archivo = new File(directorio, "Lista.csv");
        try{
            archivo.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
            this.openReadableDB();
            Cursor cursorCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT "
                    + TMOnlineTablasSQL.NOMBRE_MANGA + ", "+ TMOnlineTablasSQL.TIPO_MANGA
                    + " FROM " + TMOnlineTablasSQL.TABLA_SEGUIR
                    + " ORDER BY " + TMOnlineTablasSQL.NOMBRE_MANGA
                    + " ASC", null);
            csvWriter.writeNext(cursorCSV.getColumnNames());
            while (cursorCSV.moveToNext()){
                String[] columnas = {cursorCSV.getString(0), cursorCSV.getString(1)};
                csvWriter.writeNext(columnas);
            }
            csvWriter.close();
            cursorCSV.close();
        }catch (Exception sqlException){
            Log.e("TMODescargaError", sqlException.getMessage(), sqlException);
        }
    }else{
        //para targetSDK < 29
        File directorio = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TMO_Descarga");
        if(!directorio.exists()){
            directorio.mkdirs();
        }
        File archivo = new File(directorio, "Lista.csv");
        try{
            archivo.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
            this.openReadableDB();
            Cursor cursorCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT "
                    + TMOnlineTablasSQL.NOMBRE_MANGA + ", "+ TMOnlineTablasSQL.TIPO_MANGA
                    + " FROM " + TMOnlineTablasSQL.TABLA_SEGUIR
                    + " ORDER BY " + TMOnlineTablasSQL.NOMBRE_MANGA
                    + " ASC", null);
            csvWriter.writeNext(cursorCSV.getColumnNames());
            while (cursorCSV.moveToNext()){
                String[] columnas = {cursorCSV.getString(0), cursorCSV.getString(1)};
                csvWriter.writeNext(columnas);
            }
            csvWriter.close();
            cursorCSV.close();
        }catch (Exception sqlException){
            Log.e("TMODescargaError", sqlException.getMessage(), sqlException);
        }
    }
}
```

Y el botón me ha quedado así:

```
    btnDescargarLista.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(pedirPermisoAlmacenamiento()){
                TMOnlineMetodosSQL tmOnlineMetodosSQL = new TMOnlineMetodosSQL(TMOnlineListaMangasSiguiendo.this);
                tmOnlineMetodosSQL.descargarLista(TMOnlineListaMangasSiguiendo.this);
            }else {
                toastRojo("Debe aceptar los permisos de almacenamiento.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Al controlar las carpetas dentro del emulador, pues no ha aparecido la carpeta ni el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Lo estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que en sistemas operativos 10 y posteriores versiones ya no se tendrá acceso a ubicaciones fuera del directorio creado para tu aplicación, ahora tendrás que crear archivos y directorios dentro de la estructura definida por Android para tu aplicación:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/
```

es importante saber que el método [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) es obsoleto en API 29, que sería Android 10 y posteriores versiones, por lo tanto ahora debes crear el directorio usando el método [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)):

```
//File directorio = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TMO_Descarga");
File directorio = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "TMO_Descarga");
if(!directorio.exists()){
    directorio.mkdirs();
}
```

puedes revisar una pregunta relacionada:

[Como crear carpeta en Android 11](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425573/c%C3%B3mo-crear-carpeta-en-android-11/425683)

Revisa tamnién:

[Cambios en los comportamientos: apps orientadas a la API nivel 29 y posteriores](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10)

Por cierto únicamente necesitas este permiso para leer y escribir:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```