# No sale cuadro de dialogo de los Permisos android sdk 33

Tags: android

Tengo una app donde a la hora de pedir permisos de

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

no sale el cuadro de dialogo de los permisos: La app es de :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.valhondo.delgado.tesoreriainjurios"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

para pedir permiso lo realizo asi:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                checkExternalStoragePermission();
            } else {
                if ( rBportadores.isChecked() ) { crearpdfportadores(); }
                if ( rBtesoreria.isChecked() ) { crearpdftesoreria(); }
                if ( rBhisportadores.isChecked() ) { crearpdfhisportador(); }
                if ( rBhistesoreria.isChecked() ) { crearpdfhistesoreria(); }
                if ( rBeventos.isChecked() ) { crearpdfeventos(); }
            }
```

y el checkExternalStoragePermission(); es

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        if ( rBportadores.isChecked() ) { crearpdfportadores(); }
        if ( rBtesoreria.isChecked() ) { crearpdftesoreria(); }
        if ( rBhisportadores.isChecked() ) { crearpdfhisportador(); }
        if ( rBhistesoreria.isChecked() ) { crearpdfhistesoreria(); }
        if ( rBeventos.isChecked() ) { crearpdfeventos(); }
    }
}
```

Si el telefono es de version de android 13 no sale el dialogo y si es de version 9 se va por el else. He probado en la version 13 quitarle los controles y poner directamente

```
if ( rBportadores.isChecked() ) { crearpdfportadores(); }
        if ( rBtesoreria.isChecked() ) { crearpdftesoreria(); }
        if ( rBhisportadores.isChecked() ) { crearpdfhisportador(); }
        if ( rBhistesoreria.isChecked() ) { crearpdfhistesoreria(); }
        if ( rBeventos.isChecked() ) { crearpdfeventos(); }
```

y me funciona bien.

¿Por que no sale el cuadro de dialogo de aceptar o denegar los permisos ?

He probado muchas cosa que viene en satckoverflow pero ninguna ha funcionado.
Probare bajar la version de 33 a 32 pero estoy teniendo problema con ello.

Comment: Enredando y probando he cambiado a la version 32 desde la 33 y tambien he cambiado   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' a la version 1.5.0 y de momento ha funcionado. Pero porque no sale en esa version 33 los dialogos.

Comment: No va a salir el diálogo porque ya no será necesario, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: El permiso ya no existe en Android 13 y de hecho, a partir de Android 10 fue marcado como obsoleto.

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que tu app esta orientada para ser compilada con Android 13 ( compileSdkVersion 33 ), ahora debes leer y escribir únicamente en los directorios creados dentro de la estructura de la aplicación,

Almacenamiento interno:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/
```

Almacenamiento externo:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/
```

Revisar **[uso de getFilesDir() y getExternalFilesDir()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/425683/95)**

por lo tanto, **por cuestiones de seguridad, ya no se permitirá escribir en otra ubicación fuera de los directorios de tu app, y ya no será necesario requerir el permiso.**

Al compilar con Android 13, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` será obsoleto y deberás eliminarlo de tu AndroidManifest.xml, ya que no es necesario definirlo.